# How do I reassign numbering of Displays when you have more than 2 monitors connected to mac mini

Tags: macos, display

I have three displays connected to my mac mini. (I have used Arrangement to make sure they are connected correctly left to right, so mouse movement works correctly.) The leftmost is the primary with the dock. However, the middle display is call "Display 3" and the rigtmost is "Display 2". Even if I swap the cables, it still stays the same, so OSX must remember the displayid. This is a problem because Desktop numbering (in Spaces) are out of sequence rigt to left across the displays. It is also confusing that when you assign an app to a display, you have to remember that 3 is the middle display. I know I could just physically swap display 2 and 3, but can this be solved through macOS Display settings? :-)

Any suggestion on how one can reassign the numbering of the displays?

Comment: The ability to move the monitors around in `System Preferences... > Displays > Arrangement` does not work for you?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't solve this issue. I have used Arrangement to make sure they are connected correctly left to right, so mouse movement works correctly. But left display is still called Display 1, middle Display 3 and right call Display 2. On the left display I have Desktop 1 and 2, middle display have Desktop 6 and 7, and right display have Desktop 3, 4 and 5. Anoying.

Comment: Related if not dupes - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217468/3-monitors-in-a-row-and-i-want-the-dock-in-the-middle -  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141401/mousing-over-to-external-display and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239112/logitech-mouse-used-on-el-capitan - I think you are confusing 'displays' 'spaces' & 'desktops'

Comment: No this is not about mouse movement or the dock. All of that works correctly. This is about the numbering of the Display and Desktop (in Spaces) doesn't follow the physical placement of the displays.

Comment: Please edit your question to explicitly mention that you have used the Arrangement tab.

Comment: I'm still not certain what you are asking. Try System prefs>Mission Control> uncheck "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use"

Comment: Same problem here. The Macbook changes the numbering sometimes after sleep mode and I have no idea how to renumber them. "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use" is unchecked for me already. In addition to that, the tool named "displayplacer" (via homebrew tap) doesn't work either because it only arranges, but doesn't renumber the displays. The annoying thing is that displays become new "names"/numbers and apps open on different monitors suddenly. One has to rearrange every space etc. every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very annoying problem and I have not found any official documentation on how to control the numbering of the Desktop on each monitor. However, through a lot of trial and error, I've discovered these rules that will help you order the Desktop numbers.

First, a few key points on how the numbering behaves

- Your 'Home Screen' (the display with the Dock) will always have the lowest number (e.g. Desktop 1, Desktop 2 if it has 2 desktops)
- When you drag the Dock (in Displays >> Arrangement) from one display to another, it will swap the numbering between the two monitors that you dragged it to and from. For example if you have 3 monitors that is setup as follow

- Monitor A (Desktop 1, Desktop 2) ==DOCK LOCATION==
- Monitor B (Desktop 3, Desktop 4)
- Monitor C (Desktop 5, Desktop 6)

If you drag the DOCK from Monitor A to B, you'll end up with the following:

- Monitor A (Desktop 3, Desktop 4)
- Monitor B (Desktop 1, Desktop 2) ==DOCK LOCATION==
- Monitor C (Desktop 5, Desktop 6)

Therefore, by planning the sequence of DOCK position swaps, you can reach the final ordering that you desire.

The ordering may get messed up again if you disconnect the monitors or return from sleep or restart. I have no idea how to 'save' the settings. But at least this will help you reconfigure quickly.

Comment: Look up the app "Stay", to save and restore settings.  Works quite well, happy user here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the answer on a [similar post](https://superuser.com/a/1220526) fixed it.

It turns out all you have to do is go to **System Preferences** > **Displays** and then drag the top white bar to the display that you want to be first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question was posted before it was fixed but in Ventura you can go to System Settings -> Displays -> Arrange.  On the Arrange screen you can right click the monitor you want as your primary and set it to "Main Display".  This will set the other one is "Extended Display".

I don't yet know if this saves between logins/disconnections but it worked for me so far.